# Unity Addressables Settings missing "Build Addressables on Player Build" setting

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor, addressables

I'm using the Addressables system to both load a local addressable asset and a remote addressable asset. I can sometimes load the local asset, but not the remote asset.

But that's beside the point. In the unity documentation for the Addressable system settings, there is an option for "Build Addressables on Player Build". However, on my Addressable Settings, this option is not available.

Unity Documentation:

[image]

My Addressables Settings:

[image]

I'd very much like to turn building addressable off on Player build. So, does anyone know where this setting has gone to? In case you're wondering, the addressable documentation is version 1.19.17 and I'm also using 1.19.17.

Comment: `I'm also having a plethora of other exceptionally annoying and poorly documented issues, but let's worry about those later.` .. how about removing this sentence then? Are you asking for help or ranting about the documentation? ;) Possible that this wasn't updated since the last version (s) .. have you tried to rather reach out to them directly?

Comment: Oh I was 100% ranting and it definitely doesn't have anything to do with the question at hand. This question was written after 5 hours straight messing with unsuccessful builds, so I was probably not in a fit state to write the question at the time.Though I think your answer is sufficient. I'll look into it more later today.

Answer (score 1):

Unity 2021.3.12f1

**Edit > Preferences > Addressables**

Under *Player Build Settings* you'll find
**Build Addressables on build Player**

set value to *Do Not Build Addressables on Player Build*

Answer (score 0):

I think they just missed to update that page for the newer Unity versions (2021.2+)

From [Configuring Addressables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.19/manual/Configuration.html#unity-preferences)

> The Addressables package adds its own section to the Unity Editor Preferences window. The Addressables preferences include:
>
> ...
>
> **Build Addressables on Player Build (Unity 2021.2+)**
>
> Determines whether Unity builds Addressables content as part of your Player build.

I would just guess that according setting was removed from the Addressables System settings and you simply rather configure it here now.

---

And funny also from [Building Content](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.19/manual/Builds.html#build-with-player)

> Building Addressables on Player Build requires Unity 2021.2+. In earlier versions of Unity, you must build your Addressables content as a separate step.

So I too would wonder what this setting was good for then at all in earlier versions ^^

Comment: So I looked into the Unity Preferences window under Addressables, and the only setting in there was Debug Build Layout. The Build Addressables on Player Build setting was missing. Is there another place that that setting might be?

Comment: If you are using any version before the one mentioned, there is no that option because it does not build groups by default with the player build, while all the latter versions of Unity do so. They put it there for the cases where you have really large project so you don't want to build groups with every player build.